# How fast is the internet on board American Airlines flights?

Tags: internet, american-airlines

I'm taking a flight on AA soon and will need internet for some last-minute work. How fast should I expect it to be?

Comment: Anything from barely useable to good enough for video.  In my experience no airline is consistent across all aircraft due to different technology installed, so your mileage may vary depending on the plane you get.  Potentially weather and other factors apply as well.

Comment: In addition the aircraft will have a fixed internet bandwidth, so the speed you achieve will be dependent on the number of people accessing the internet at the same time.  At best you can ask what would the minimum speed potentially be, but even that may depend on the actual aircraft you are flying on.

Comment: FYI [How can I approximate ahead of time the wifi speed and robustness of some wifi on the plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/163034/1810)

Comment: As far as I understand it, for some airlines at least, there is a big difference between the service available over land (and specifically over the continental US) and what you get on transoceanic flights. Completely different technologies and costs which result in very different speeds (and costs, sometimes).

Comment: Depending on the type of plane and on which stage of the flight you're in, it must be somewhere between a few hundred km/h and several hundred km/h.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, flying over the Continental US, the speeds [were as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF5Kk.png):

Download: 2.5 Mbps
Upload: 7.5 Mbps
Latency: 665 ms

Comment: How full/empty was the plane?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt 90% full